# Refresh ascx from button click

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webusercontrol

How to refresh another user control declared in a ascx page from button click event of that page(ascx.cs)?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? Show us the code that doesn't work, then we can help you

Comment: The question is how to refresh a usercontrol in a page on Page PostBack? I guess now its clear

Answer (score 0):

You can load it dynamically.

First from page load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
    LoadControl();
    }
}
```

And then load it from a button again on which you want to reload it

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    LoadControl();

}




  private void LoadControl()
    {
    usercontrols_SimpleControl ucSimpleControl =  LoadControl("~/UserControlName.ascx") as usercontrols_SimpleControl;
    Placeholder1.Controls.Add(ucSimpleControl);
    }
```